# How do I update pandas dataframes with calculations done group-wise?

Tags: python, pandas

Take the following table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[10,20,30,40]})
print(df.to_string())

   a  b   c
0  1  1  10
1  1  2  20
2  2  3  30
3  2  4  40
```

I would like the following result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4], 'c':[10,20,30,40], 'group_avg':[13.5,13.5,31.5,31.5]})
print(result.to_string())

   a  b   c  group_avg
0  1  1  10       13.5
1  1  2  20       13.5
2  2  3  30       31.5
3  2  4  40       31.5
```

That is, group_avg is computed by doing c-b and then taking the average group-wise by grouping on a.

Is there a nice way of doing this, or do I have to go the roundabout way of creating a new difference column, grouping by a, getting the average, then joining the result on the original table?

What if I want to apply an arbitrary function which takes 2 series, but I want to apply it group-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, using `assign` to create a temporary column of c-b then, `groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['group_avg'] = df.assign(avg = df.c - df.b)\
                    .groupby('a')['avg'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c  group_avg
0  1  1  10       13.5
1  1  2  20       13.5
2  2  3  30       31.5
3  2  4  40       31.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the linear nature of the `mean`, the mean of the difference is the same as the difference of the mean.  So we can use the `mean` after a `groupby` then subtract.

```
df.join(df.groupby('a').mean().eval('c - b').rename('avg'), on='a')

   a  b   c   avg
0  1  1  10  13.5
1  1  2  20  13.5
2  2  3  30  31.5
3  2  4  40  31.5
```